# How to pip install two dependancies with same folder structure like "gedev/htcloud/dependency1" and "gedev/htcloud/dependency2"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation

I am trying to install a dependency which will be installed like the directory structure `gedev/htcloud/dependency1` and then install another dependency with directory structure `gedev/htcloud/dependency2`. I expect the final result to be `gedev/htcloud/dependency1,dependency2` but I am getting only `dependency2` folder inside htcloud

Comment: Can you show the commands you're running & output you're receiving?

Comment: To not override each other these two dependencies must be [namespace packages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+namespace+package).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to install them two times, each time with one dependenciesx.txt using

```
pip install -r dependenciesx.txt -t /path/to/your/directory
```

But I think it's not the best way

Answer (score 0):

Your wildcard expression is incorrect. If your shell supports brace expansion (like Bash does), the correct syntax is

```
pip install gedev/htcloud/{dependency1,dependency2}
```

or equivalently, in any shell

```
gedev/htcloud/dependency[12]
```

if the directory names indeed only differ by a single character.